# Get json value from mysql database and display its elements properly

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

**I have Json value in my mysql database column like the following**

```
{"2":{"label":"","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"3":{"label":"location","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/?page_id=320","type":"hidden","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"1000","tooltip":"","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"4":{"label":"Name","value":"fjedhfjkhre","type":"text","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field0","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"5":{"label":"Email","value":"hjjkhkj@jhjkh.com","type":"email","validation":"email","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field1","custom":"","custom2":"","custom3":"zz","custom4":"","custom5":""},"6":{"label":"Files","value":"3","type":"upload","validation":"file","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field2","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"7":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Desert.jpg","type":"file0","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"8":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Jellyfish.jpg","type":"file1","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"9":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Lighthouse.jpg","type":"file2","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"10":{"label":"Comments","value":"hoi this is a cijkmkmkm","type":"para","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field3","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"11":{"label":"Date","value":"01-15-2014","type":"date","validation":"date","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field4","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"12":{"label":"Profession","value":"Option A","type":"radio","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field5","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"13":{"label":"title","value":"Form Title","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"0":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null},"1":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null}}
```

***I want to get proper values from it like email, file url....etc.***

*i am using this.*

```
   global $wpdb;         
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_submissions ORDER BY id");       
if(!empty($results)) { 
     foreach($results as $r) {   
          echo "<p>".$r->content."</p>";
          $json_object=$r->content;
            }
            $arr = json_decode($json_object);
 echo echo $arr['0'];
} else {
     echo "<p>Boo, we couldn't find anything that is in all these groups. Try removing a category!</p>";         
}
```

when i echo *r->content* it display all the json value as above. but i unable to decode and get json array elemt result.

This is a form data so i want to display the enteries in a table.

**Thanks if someone help me.**

Answer (score 0):

The format of that JSON seems weird, but you can't access it like an Array, since it's an object.

The attribute "2" of that object, for instance, is another object; You can acess it using

```
<?
    //beeing $a that giant json string
    $object = json_decode($a);
    print_r($object->{"2"});
    print_r($object->{"2"}->custom3);
?>
```

Could you try this sintax, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have tried json_decode($data,true);

```
$data  = '{"2":{"label":"","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"3":{"label":"location","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/?page_id=320","type":"hidden","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"1000","tooltip":"","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"4":{"label":"Name","value":"fjedhfjkhre","type":"text","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field0","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"5":{"label":"Email","value":"hjjkhkj@jhjkh.com","type":"email","validation":"email","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field1","custom":"","custom2":"","custom3":"zz","custom4":"","custom5":""},"6":{"label":"Files","value":"3","type":"upload","validation":"file","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field2","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"7":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Desert.jpg","type":"file0","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"8":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Jellyfish.jpg","type":"file1","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"9":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/plugins\/formcraft\/file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/Lighthouse.jpg","type":"file2","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"10":{"label":"Comments","value":"hoi this is a cijkmkmkm","type":"para","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field3","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"11":{"label":"Date","value":"01-15-2014","type":"date","validation":"date","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field4","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"12":{"label":"Profession","value":"Option A","type":"radio","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field5","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"13":{"label":"title","value":"Form Title","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"0":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null},"1":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null}}
';

$result = json_decode($data,true);

foreach($result as $key=>$val){
 echo $val["label"];
 // Other elements you can display as well
}
```

Also make sure to run a check something like **if(array_key_exists($val["label"]))** before doing echo this will make sure not throwing any notice if the element is not there in the array